# Regexp for handling "test-12-1"-like strings (php)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need some help with writing regexp to parse input strings like this ones:

`test-12-1`

`blabla12412-5`

`t-dsf-gsdg-x-10`

to next matches:

`test` and `1`

`blabla12412` and `5`

`t-dsf-gsdg-x` and `10`

I try to reach it by using something like

```
$matches = [];
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-\d+)+$/', 'test-12-1', $matches);
```

But I received unexpected result:

```
 array (
   0 => 'test-12-1',
   1 => '-1',
 )
```

You can move forward with help on this playground: [https://ru.functions-online.com/preg_match.html?command={"pattern":"/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-\d+)+$/","subject":"test-12-1"}](https://ru.functions-online.com/preg_match.html?command=%7B%22pattern%22:%22%5C/%5E[a-zA-Z0-9]%20(-%5C%5Cd%20)%20$%5C/%22,%22subject%22:%22test-12-1%22%7D)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you want `test-12` and `1` or `test`, `12` and `1`.  It's not clear in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^(.*?)(?:-(\d+))+$~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6XTLmB/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:-(\d+))+` - 1 or more occurrences of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits (the last occurrence is kept in the group value since it is located in a repeated non-capturing group)
- `$` - end of string.

[image]

Comment: Is there any advantage here over simply ^(.*?)-(\d+)+$  since that will capture the last group anyway?

Comment: Thanks for useful answer! But "test-12-1" handle as "test" and "1" instead of "test-12" and "1"...

Comment: @NewEXE Look at your question, this is what you asked for. `test-12-1` should yield `test` and `1`. Else, use `'~^(.*)-(\d+)$~'`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/6XTLmB/2).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, totally my bad, sorry for this! I need more sleep...